# most efficient way to count the largest value in swift

Tags: loops, math, swift3

I have written the following program which calculates the **largest** value(`counter`) returned by a function `collatzSequence(value: Int)`. However, whenever I run it through the function `countLongestCollatzSequence()`, Xcode always crashes. What can I do to make this code better(or run)?

Thank you.

```
func collatzSequence(value: Int) -> Int {
    var currentNumber: Int = value
    var counter: Int = 0
    while (currentNumber != 1) {
        if currentNumber % 2 == 0 {
            currentNumber = currentNumber / 2
            counter = counter + 1
        }
        else {
            currentNumber = (( currentNumber * 3 ) + 1 ) / 2
            counter = counter + 2
        }
    }
    return counter
}


func countLongestCollatzSequence() {
    var currentValue: Int = 0
    var largestValue: Int = 0
    for x in (50000...1000000).reversed() {
        currentValue = collatzSequence(value: x)
        if largestValue < currentValue {
            largestValue = currentValue
        }
    }
}

countLongestCollatzSequence()
```

PS: For clarity, the first function generates a sequence of numbers and the second function finds out which sequence was the longest.

Comment: You're approach of calculating each value separately is hugely inefficient. It's like counting "1, 1 2, 1 2 3, 1 2 3 4" instead of just "1, 2, 3, 4"

Comment: @Alexander, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Rob The crash does not give any message. Rather, Xcode becomes unresponsive and I have to force quit. The following code was tested in PlayGround.

Comment: @SamanRay I'm working on this problem, give me some time.

Comment: Run the code in an app, and you'll see it runs fine. Its a playground thing.

Comment: @Rob Thank you. Is there a way to make the code efficient?

Comment: Sure, but when I ran this in app with optimizations on (i.e. a release build rather than debug build), it took less than 0.3 seconds on my MacBook Pro, so I'm not sure whether you need to go crazy optimizing this. I feel like there's some broader context to this question that you haven't shared with us. What precisely are you trying to do?

Comment: @Rob I was trying to solve project Euler problems. https://projecteuler.net/problem=14

Comment: I wouldn't lose sleep over why the playground is choking. I'd just do it in a stand-alone app, solve the problem in 0.3 seconds, and declare success. Why kill yourself refining it further? Note, you're calculating what the length of the longest sequence, but not capturing what number generated that sequence. But that's an easy fix.

Comment: @Rob thank you so much. I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob mentioned, you'll want to compile this into a standalone program with compiler optimizations enabled. You should never benchmark in the playground.

I took the liberty to write a memoized version of this algorithm, and it's really damn fast.

Firstly, it's important to be able to generate sequences lazily, rather than always being stuck having to compute an entire sequence. Consider the case of `n = 8`. It produces the sequence `[8, 4, 2, 1]`, which has length 4. Suppose I wanted to calculate the sequence for `n = 5` right after. I would get `[5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]`, which has length 6. Notice that the last 8 elements are the same. As it turns out, if I were generating this element piece by piece, I could get `[5, 16,`, reach `8` and then I know that I can stop expanding the sequence. Instead I can just return the number of elements I have so far (`2`), plus the size of the sequence for `n = 8` (`4`). This allows me to short circuit a ***vast*** majority of the calculation.

Here is my implementation of the `CollatzSequence`:

```
struct CollatzSequence: Sequence {
    let n: Int

    init(_ n: Int) { self.n = n }

    public func makeIterator() -> CollatzIterator {
        return CollatzIterator(n)
    }
}

struct CollatzIterator: IteratorProtocol {
    var n: Int
    var done = false

    init(_ n: Int) { self.n = n }

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        guard n > 1 else {
            guard !done else { return nil }
            done = true;
            return 1
        }

        defer {
            n = (n % 2 == 0)
                ? n/2 // even case
                : 3*n + 1 // odd case
        }

        return n
    }
}
```

Next I made a calculator that computes the length of any given `CollatzSequence`. Importantly, it keeps a history of inputs and their sizes, in a dictionary I called `memoizedCounts`. This dictionary is initialized with the base case, `n = 1` produces the sequence `[1]`, which has length 1.

```
struct CollatzSequenceLengthCalculator {
    var memoizedCounts = [1: 1]

    var previousElements = [Int]() // shared instance to save cost of reallocation

    mutating func lengthOfSequence(startingAt n: Int) -> Int {
//      print("====== n: \(n)")
        if let existingCount = memoizedCounts[n] {
//          print("Cache hit: counts[\(n)] is \(existingCount)")
            return existingCount
        }

        previousElements.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

        for i in CollatzSequence(n) {
            guard let existingCount = memoizedCounts[i] else {
//              print("No existing count for \(i)")
                previousElements.append(i)
                continue
            }

//          print("Cache hit: counts[\(i)] is \(existingCount).")
//          print("Going back to fill in previous these cache misses: \(previousElements)")

            for (offset, element) in previousElements.reversed().enumerated() {
                let newCount = offset + existingCount + 1
//              print("\tSetting counts[\(element)] to \(newCount)")
                memoizedCounts[element] = newCount
            }

            return existingCount + previousElements.count
        }

        fatalError("This should never happen")
    }
}
```

I also made a benchmark to compare how many sequence elements were computed in this optimized algorithm vs. the naive approach:

```
extension CollatzSequenceLengthCalculator {
    mutating func debug_lengthOfSequence(startingAt n: Int)
        -> (result: Int, numIterations: Int) {
//      print("====== n: \(n)")
        if let existingCount = memoizedCounts[n] { // redunant here to speed up common base case
//          print("Cache hit: counts[\(n)] is \(existingCount)")
            return (result: existingCount, numIterations: 0)
        }

        previousElements.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

        for i in CollatzSequence(n) {
            guard let existingCount = memoizedCounts[i] else {
//              print("No existing count for \(i)")
                previousElements.append(i)
                continue
            }

//          print("Cache hit: counts[\(i)] is \(existingCount).")
//          print("Going back to fill in previous these cache misses: \(previousElements)")

            for (offset, element) in previousElements.reversed().enumerated() {
                let newCount = offset + existingCount + 1
//              print("\tSetting counts[\(element)] to \(newCount)")
                memoizedCounts[element] = newCount
            }

            return (result: existingCount + previousElements.count, numIterations: previousElements.count)
        }

        fatalError("This should never happen")
    }
}

let input = 1...10000
var debugCalc = CollatzSequenceLengthCalculator()
let debug: [(input: Int, result: Int, numIterations: Int)] = input.map {
    let (result, numIterations) = debugCalc.debug_lengthOfSequence(startingAt: $0)
    return (input: $0, result: result, numIterations: numIterations)
}

//debug.forEach{ print($0) }

print("Total unoptimized iterations: \( debug.map{ $0.result }.reduce(0, +))")
print("Total optimized iterations: \( debug.map{ $0.numIterations }.reduce(0, +))")
```

I found that calculating all sequences for `n` in `1...100_000_000`, the naive algorithm would have to calculate `18_023_493_583` sequence elements, whereas my optimized algorithm would take only `217_289_746`. That's a decrease of **98.8 %**!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this in a playground, which has a lot of overhead (e.g., keeping track of values as you're going along), and for reasons that aren't entirely obvious, causes serious problems for the playground.

If you put this code in a stand-alone app, it runs fairly quickly. And if you run this as a release build (i.e. with optimizations turned on), it runs even more quickly (0.3 seconds on my MacBook Pro).

Bottom line, playgrounds aren't ideally suited for maximal efficiency, so if you want to run this most efficiently, I'd just put the code in a stand-alone app and I think you'll be satisfied with the efficiency of your existing algorithm.

---

Re Alexander's memoized approach, this is discussed in WWDC 2014 video [Advanced Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/404/).